# Common identifier for flow or transactions between nodes

Tags: corda

Using a client to listen on vault updates `proxy.vaultTrackBy` on multiple nodes, I can't identify a parameter to reference the end of the same transaction across multiple nodes. 
Tried: `flowId`, `hashCode` also looking into states but produced and consumed are empty.

Any other identifier or is this intended?

Comment: `vaultTrackBy` returns information on states, not transactions or flows. Are you trying to identify the same transaction across nodes, or the same state?

Comment: Any identifier would be enough, either state or transaction

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we purposefully avoid sending any kind of invocation ID outside of the node boundaries, since this is private node information and shouldn't be shared for privacy reasons. You have a few options:

- If the transaction records the same state in both nodes' vaults, you can check the `Vault<Update>` object produced on both sides to ensure that the same `StateAndRef` appears in both nodes' vaults

  - If `consumed` and `produced` are empty, check that the nodes are recording the states in their vault. This is determined by:

    - Whether they are the owner (for `OwnableState`s)
    - Whether they are a participant (for other state types)
    - Whether they are recording the transaction as a participant
- Do something like the following in your flows to notify yourself that the transaction has occurred (where `myEventPublishingService` is your own API):

  ```
  @Suspendable
  fun call() {
      val proposal = session.receive<TransactionBuilder>().unwrap { it }
      checkThatTheOtherPartyIsNotScammingMe(proposal)

      <here, before signing the transaction and sending it over>

      myEventPublishingService.publish(
          TransactionApprovedEvent.from(proposal, otherParty))

      proposal.sign(services)
      session.send(proposal)
  }
  ```